# How to get a collection of child ids [Ruby on Rails 4.2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

I have two models.

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many: assets
end

class Assets < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many: experiences
end
```

In my Experience controller, I'm trying to get a collection of Assets that are associated to an Experience. (parent-child)

I'm currently using `will_paginate` gem, and trying to build a collection for this to pass in the collection argument.

```
will_paginate(collection, options)
```

How would i do this?

Comment: I think this code won't even boot up (invalid ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Your model relationship should be:

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many: assets
end

class Assets < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: experience
end
```

In Experience Controller, to get associated Assets

```
# single experience data
@experience = Experience.first
@experience.assets


# multiple experiences data
@experiences = Experience.all.includes(:assets)

# you can also use this in view
@experiences.each do |x|
  x.assets.each do |a|
    a.title (ex. field name)
    ...
  end
end
```